# trying to upload profile picture with people api

Tags: python, api, google-api, google-people-api

I have a python script and I wanted to upload a profile picture, is it possible with people API?
I looked at the documentation but could not find anything relevant.

Comment: did you try [contact.update](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact) and setting it to people/me ?   TBH i have never tried.   If you have any issues post your code love to know if it works.

Comment: yes, that is what I used when creating my program for creating and updating people, the only thing I am missing is adding the profile picture.

Comment: its not personfield photos?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is only for GET requests.

Comment: Do you want to upload profile pictures for Contacts or for the Google account profile? If it's the former I don't think this is possible and you might want to file a feature request in Issue Tracker. If it's the latter and you have admin access, you could use https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users.photos/update

Answer (score 0):

Note I haven't tried but.

If we use [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22photos%22%7D&apix=true) This returns my profile picture.

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/1172004755326775346",
  "etag": "%EgQBAy43GgQBAgUHIgxHcHNCRHZycjVkZz0=",
  "photos": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "1172004755326775346"
        }
      },
      "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/ACNPEu8rJvpl_iNqmdR9yLdGv7gSikYi4mSCd_K6DuQYCNw=s100"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "3faa96eb08baa4be"
        }
      },
      "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/contacts/ABsqplv0nK0ZiL8S_0F4PS2sNCZKID_Ihlazp6gIoUUyLmoLOrZUigNy=s100"
    }
  ]
}
```

Which would imply to me that [update.contact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact) with a user of people/me and a personFields of photo should allow you to upload the users photo.

As for the code to actually do the upload I would have a look at the  [manage upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads) example for google drive and you should be able to piece together how the python client library will let you upload a file.  If it doesnt work edit your question add your code and i will see if i can help.

Comment: I did see "photos" however it is only for GET, when trying with POST or UPDATE it is not allowed. Thank you for trying.

Comment: if I can find some time I will give it a try tomorrow otherwise consider adding it as a feature request